# Como pasar de una columna a otra si en la primera columna todos los valores ya están en cero PHP Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

estoy desarrollando un sistema en donde un usuario tiene puntos acumulados en varias columnas. Estos puntos tienen la posibilidad de ser transferidos a otro usuario.

Mi tabla se llama puntos y tiene 3 columnas que son `disc_puntualidad_pos, productividad_pos, gestion_pos`

La suma total de estas columnas equivalen al crédito disponible a transferir de un usuario.

Mi formulario

```
<form action="{{url('/transferencia/enviar')}}" method="POST">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="number" name="monto" class="form-control" placeholder="TOTAL A TRANSFERIR" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="number" name="cuenta" class="form-control" placeholder="CUENTA DESTINATARIO" required>
        </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="punto_acumulado" class="form-control" value="{{$puntos_acumulados[0]->r}}" required>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">CONFIRMAR TRANSFERENCIA</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Mi formulario esta enviando como se puede ver, el monto a transferir, al numero de cuenta a transferir y el punto acumulado disponible a transferir.

Mi controlador:

```
public function transferir(Request $request) {
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $monto_a_transferir = $request->monto;
    $monto_ya_transferido = 0;
    $puntos_acumulados = $request->punto_acumulado;
    $user_a_regalar = $request->cuenta;
    $user_a_transferir = DB::select("SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE id = '$request->cuenta'");
    $registros = DB::select('SELECT id, disc_puntualidad_pos, productividad_pos, gestion_pos from puntos where user_id ='. $user_id);
    $cantidad_registros = count($registros);
    $acumulado = 0;

    //Acá controlo si hay credito disponible al solicitado 
    if ($monto_a_transferir <= $puntos_acumulados) {
        //aca si existe el usuario al que quiere transferir
        if ($user_a_transferir) {
           //aca realizo un recorrido de todas las columnas para acceder al registro para descontar
            for ($i=0; $i < $cantidad_registros; $i++) {

                if ($monto_a_transferir > $acumulado) {
                //mi variable acumulado se inicializa en 0 pero va aumentando
                    if ($registros[$i]->disc_puntualidad_pos > 0) {

                        $acumulado = $acumulado + $registros[$i]->disc_puntualidad_pos;
                        //aca el acumulado recibe el valor del registro de la columna disc_puntualidad_pos
                        //y pregunta si es igual mayor o menor... hasta que se cumpla los puntos
                        if ($acumulado ==  $monto_a_transferir) {
                            var_dump('acumulado ya es igual al monto a transferir '.$acumulado);

                            // actualiza el registro
                            $punto = Punto::findOrFail($registros[$i]->id);
                            $punto->disc_puntualidad_pos = 0;
                            $punto->save();

                            // registra la transeferencia
                            $regalo = new Regalo();
                            $regalo->puntos = $acumulado;
                            $regalo->user_regalo = $user_id;
                            $regalo->user_recibio = $user_a_regalar;
                            $regalo->save();
                            var_dump('se regalo');

                        }

                        if ($acumulado <  $monto_a_transferir) {

                            var_dump('el acumulado quedo en '. $acumulado . ' y el monto a transferir es '. $monto_a_transferir);

                            // actualiza el registro
                            $punto = Punto::findOrFail($registros[$i]->id);
                            $punto->disc_puntualidad_pos = 0;
                            $punto->save();

                        }

                        if ($acumulado > $monto_a_transferir) {
                            var_dump('el acumulado '. $acumulado . ' ya paso al monto a transferir '. $monto_a_transferir);
                            $vuelto = $acumulado - $monto_a_transferir;

                            // actualiza el registro
                            $punto = Punto::findOrFail($registros[$i]->id);
                            $punto->disc_puntualidad_pos = $vuelto;
                            $punto->save();

                            // registra la transeferencia
                            $regalo = new Regalo();
                            $regalo->puntos = $monto_a_transferir;
                            $regalo->user_regalo = $user_id;
                            $regalo->user_recibio = $user_a_regalar;
                            $regalo->save();
                        }
                    }



                }
            }
        } else {
            var_dump('no hay usuario');
        }
    } else {
        var_dump('el monto es mayor al punto acumulado');
    }
    // var_dump('se sumo'.$acumulado);
    var_dump('--------'); die;
    return redirect('/transferencia');

}
```

El codigo lo que hace es recorre la columna disc_puntualidad_pos hasta obtener los puntos necesarios para la transferencia,

en el codigo del controlador explico el codigo... mi pregunta es si yo quiero transferir 100 puntos de 200 y en mi columna `disc_puntualidad_pos` tengo 50, como hago para descontar los puntos disponibles de `productividad_pos` en donde en suposición hay 30, y cuando eso no baste entrar a la ultima columna `gestion_pos` en donde se encuentran otros 120 puntos a descontar.

Se que puede ser un poco confuso.. cualquier duda me lo comentan.

Comment: Solo por curiosidad, ¿por qué no haces las consultas con Eloquent? veo que las dos primeras son SQL puro.

Comment: No lo se, costumbre jaja

Comment: Pues realmente estás desaprovechando algo muy útil y sencillo de Laravel y Eloquent, en cuanto al problema de la pregunta, realmente es algo sencillo de hacer con php, pero infortunadamente no tengo el tiempo de redactar una respuesta.

Comment: Podrías hacer un esfuerzo y ayudarme por favor? realmente estoy atascado en esto..